# spring mybatis with external jar dao

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jvm, mybatis

I am developing two Spring-Mybatis projects which need same DAO class because they are connecting to the same Database.

I generated jar for the DAO classes and put it into the classpath.

But Mybatis could not find the classes because Tomcat and Spring did yet to load the DAO jar at Mybatis's initialization life cycle.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/database-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse config resource: class path resource [com/test/ca/mybatis-config.xml]; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error registering typeAlias for 'AgentInfo'. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: com.test.ca.domain.AgentInfo
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:610)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5017)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5531)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse config resource: class path resource [com/test/ca/mybatis-config.xml]; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error registering typeAlias for 'AgentInfo'. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: com.test.ca.domain.AgentInfo
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.buildSqlSessionFactory(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:434)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:340)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error registering typeAlias for 'AgentInfo'. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: com.test.ca.domain.AgentInfo
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.parseConfiguration(XMLConfigBuilder.java:106)
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.parse(XMLConfigBuilder.java:89)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.buildSqlSessionFactory(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:428)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error registering typeAlias for 'AgentInfo'. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: com.test.ca.domain.AgentInfo
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.typeAliasesElement(XMLConfigBuilder.java:127)
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.parseConfiguration(XMLConfigBuilder.java:96)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: com.test.ca.domain.AgentInfo
    at org.apache.ibatis.io.ClassLoaderWrapper.classForName(ClassLoaderWrapper.java:188)
    at org.apache.ibatis.io.ClassLoaderWrapper.classForName(ClassLoaderWrapper.java:87)
    at org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources.classForName(Resources.java:254)
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.typeAliasesElement(XMLConfigBuilder.java:120)
```

So I put the jar in tomcat/lib folder, but I need to add all the dependency jars in the folder in order to avoid ClassNotFoundException.

I am trying this because I don't want to create the same DAO classes twice.

Any one can help me?

Comment: You need to clarify your question. It is too broad now.

Answer (score 1):

It is extremely tedious to put all dependency jars in your project.

I would advice you to integrate maven to you existing project and give dependency of your dao jar.

If your dao jar has dependency on some other classes maven will download it for you.